# Programming Practice Exception Handling

Tags: exception

Is it a bad or Good programming practice if i have a code like this for my exception :

```
try
{
.....
}

catch (abcException a)
{

...do this...
...display this on screen...
...button press event handler code...
}
```

Comment: The code in your catch block will only execute if an exception was thrown. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Microsoft's best practice for exception handling is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx. However, the problem you have with the above code is that you can only use this in a GUI application (say WinForms). If you put this in a assembly then it must have GUI references on it. Better to throw the exception up the chain (with just a simple throw) if you intend to do this and let the parent application deal with it. At best you probably want the ...do this... and some logging perhaps.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Yes. I wish if exception occurs i provide user a way to go back to last page/screen/form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is perfectly fine, I mean after event handling you may execute your desired function or gracefully keep running your code too.

Scenario such as, Oops we could not connect to a bluetooth device because of blah blah blah exception, and then ask user would you like to try again or cancel, If they click try again than recursively call same function which hits your try catch block again...(Do this after certain second of countdown)

Still it depends :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if an exception happens, you need to know about it, so most of the time you should be able to display your errors using ifs statements. Again, it depends for what purpose you're using your Try/Catch.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say bad practice because you really don't want to be handling exceptions while handling an exception.  To minimize the chance of that, your exception handler should be short and sweet.  Do the user interaction outside the handler.